# Multiple subscriber email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

For my scenario, within a Contact Builder there are multiple email fields for a subscriber. How do we configure the priority order of these email addresses in marketing cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to setting the priority of addresses that are sent from Send Email Activities in a Journey Builder Interaction. You need to do a couple of things here.

Firstly set the Channel Address Order in Contact Builder which will determine the priority in which email field is used. Select **Contacts Configuration** menu option in Contact Builder, then click **Edit** in the email panel and **Add Address**. You can then add an email field from sendable Data Extensions that are used in your Contact model.

You can change the order by dragging the fields up and down in the interface. Click **Save** for your changes to apply.

Next, open your Interaction in Journey Builder, click on the Settings icon (a small cog icon in the top right corner of the version panel) and ensure that the Primary Email is set to 'Use Channel Address Order in Contact Builder' as per the screenshot below.

[image: Interaction Settings]